# how can I find the qutient of this subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N\lhd G$. For every $x\in G-N$ we have
$$C_G(x)N/N\leq C_{G/N}(Nx)$$
where $C_G(x)$ is the centralizer of $x$ in $G$. But I don't know what is the qutient.

In fact I want to know the $[C_{G/N}(Nx):C_G(x)N/N]$.
It is more important when $N=Z(G)$.

Comment: Writing quotient groups as straight fractions can look somehow confusing. I think it's better with a slash.

Comment: Well the answer depends on $G$, $N$ and $x$. It is not clear what kind of answer your are looking for!